# Directly launch SwiftUI Main App in existing UIKit project

Tags: swiftui, uikit, program-entry-point, language-interoperability

I revamp all my view controllers in SwiftUI. But still i am bound to use hostingVC for launching my SwiftUI views from scene delegate like below

```
let splashVCHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SplashView())
self.window.rootViewController = splashVCHostingController
```

I want my UIKit project to directly launch my SwiftUI app which appears like this

```
@main
struct MainAppStruct: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor var delegate: AppDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SplashView()
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me achieving this.

Comment: So just remove your scene delegate?

Comment: Yes, it started calling MainAppstruct. thanks a lot dear.